# Execute procedure with SQL statement with parameter by groovy

Tags: sql-server, groovy, execute

Client SQL Procedure starts like this and they are wainting for value: @Firma

```
EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[Aktualizace_stavba_data]

@Firma 

GO
```

---

GROOVY SCRIPT - which I need to edit with your help:

```
import de.uplanet.scripting.groovy.util.Safely

def conn  = g_dbConnections["IPOS20016"]

String Firma= g_request.get("Firma"); //prepared value

//now I dont know how to implement and also write correctly the rest of the script.

def strCall = "{call inc(2,3)}"

def call = conn.prepareCall(strCall)
call.execute()

def rs = call.getResultSet()
def contentProc

while (rs.next()){
contentProc = rs.getInt(1)
}

rs = Safely.close(rs)
stmt = Safely.close(call)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following to call a stored proc that takes a parameter and returns one VARCHAR value. In Groovy you generally don't use resultSet.

```
conn.query("{? = call dbo.Aktualizace_stavba_data(?)}", [Sql.out(Sql.VARCHAR.type), 'parm1']) { returned ->
    println "returned: ${returned}"
}
```

EDIT: I removed the first '? = ' from the query, it was a mistake. Official documentation here: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/sql-userguide.html#_stored_procedures

Comment: de.uplanet.lucy.server.workflow.WorkflowException: No such property: Sql for class: scriptA335EB759D58EEBE4A9C259D26EC14C9A7F7AC42

Comment: did you `import groovy.sql.Sql` ? And is your connection a `def conn = Sql.newInstance('your connection string here')` ?

Comment: @out_ryperd  ```import groovy.sql.Sql
id_a =1
id_b =2
id_c = "test"
def conn = Sql.newInstance(g_dbConnections["IPOS20016"])
conn.query("? = {? = call dbo.Aktualizace_stavba_data(?)}", [Sql.out(Sql.VARCHAR.type), id_a]) { returned ->
    println "returned: ${returned}"
}```

Comment: @longrisko I removed the first ? = from the query section. I added a link to the Groovy docs.

Comment: we are getting really close!  I am getting error : "SQLState: S0004: Procedure or function 'Aktualizace_stavba_data' expects parameter '@StavbaSid', which was not supplied. " Not sure how to assign String Firma= g_request.get("Firma"); //prepared value to required parameter from procedure "@StavbaSid" - can you please send me a whole code? Thank you