# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script2422592d$_run_closure1.doCall()

Tags: groovy, plsql, apache-nifi

I try to call a stored procedure in Nifi using Groovy.
I use the method described in the documentation :

> ```
> sql.call("{call CONCAT_NAME(?, ?, ?)}", [Sql.VARCHAR, 'Dierk', 'Koenig']) {
>  fullname -> assert fullname == 'Dierk Koenig'
> }
> ```

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/sql-userguide.html

my script :

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.nifi.controller.ControllerService
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback
import java.nio.charset.*
import groovy.sql.OutParameter
import groovy.sql.Sql
import java.sql.ResultSet


////Get the session values from Nifi flow Start 
def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
  String TYPE_NOTIFICATION = flowFile.getAttribute('TYPE_NOTIFICATION')
  String ID_NOTIFICATION = flowFile.getAttribute('ID_NOTIFICATION')
////Get the session values from Nifi flow END
 
 

String sqlString ="""{call PKG_TEST.P_TEST(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}""";

def parametersList = [ID_NOTIFICATION, TYPE_NOTIFICATION,Sql.VARCHAR,Sql.VARCHAR,Sql.DATE,Sql.VARCHAR,Sql.VARCHAR,Sql.VARCHAR,Sql.VARCHAR,Sql.VARCHAR,Sql.DATE ];
 
 
SQL.mydbxx.call(sqlString, parametersList) {out1, out2,...->
    flowFile.putAttribute("out1",out1)...
};

 

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

I have the following error :

> ```
> 2022-06-17 13:38:53,353 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9]
> o.a.n.p.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript
> ExecuteGroovyScript[id=26ab18f1-3b0c-18cf-d90b-3d5904676458]
> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
> Script6a6d0a35$_run_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument
> types: (String, String, java.sql.Date, null, String, null, null,
> String...) values: [xxxx, xxxx, 2022-05-30, null, OK, null, null,
> ...]: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
> Script6a6d0a35$_run_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument
> types: (String, String, java.sql.Date, null, String, null, null,
> String...) values: [xxxx,xxxx, 2022-05-30, null, OK, null, null, ...]
> ```

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61518286/3355860) answer helps

Comment: This is what I did and I have an error in the closure part (I added my script)

Comment: In the other answer, Sql.out(Sql.VARCHAR.type) specifies the returned value's type. Do you separately declare input params and return values as in that example ? Or are all your parameters return values from the SP ?

Comment: In parametersList I put In params and the types of OUT params like the SP CONCAT_NAME in the documentation